# Detect day through UTC-5 and obtain variable value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, utc

Hello everyone have this variable in JavaScript

```js
gateco = {
  "thursday": [{
    "open": "12:00",
    "close": "18:49"
  }],
  "friday": [{
    "open": "12:00",
    "close": "18:59"
  }]
};
```

How to get the day of UTC-5 time and access the open and close values respectively according to the day?

Comment: the problem is accessing the data of the variable.
Try gateco.thursday but with no results

Comment: I solved it this way, now I find myself with the mess of only getting the day of the JSON.parse(gateco) and I agree console.log(gateco.thursday[0].open);

Comment: i solved
gateco = JSON.parse(t.restaurant.schedule_data), 
weekday = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'][new Date().getDay()],

Comment: Now as one those 2 variables to get?
I tried this but it doesn't work
console.log(gateco.weekday);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that...
[see time zone list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

```js
const
  dateTimeOption =
    { timeZone : 'Etc/GMT+5'
    , hour12   : false
    , weekday  : 'long'
    , hour     : '2-digit'
    , minute   : '2-digit' 
    }
, gateco =
    { thursday : [ { open: '12:00', close: '18:49' } ]  // why is it an Array ?
    , friday   : [ { open: '12:00', close: '18:59' } ] 
    } 

let isOpenNow  = false
  , [wDay,h,m] = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', dateTimeOption)
                  .format(new Date())
                  .split(/:| /)
                  .map(s=>Number(s)||s.toLowerCase() )                  

if ( gateco[wDay] )
  {
  let hm = (h *100) +m // simplied for comparing 
    , h_m_Open  = gateco[wDay][0].open
                    .split(':')
                    .reduce((hm,t,i)=>hm + (!i?100:1)*Number(t) ,0)
    , h_m_Close = gateco[wDay][0].close
                    .split(':')
                    .reduce((hm,t,i)=>hm + (!i?100:1)*Number(t) ,0)

  isOpenNow = (h_m_Open <= hm  && hm <= h_m_Close)
  }             
//console.log( wDay,h,m )
console.log( 'isOpenNow = ', isOpenNow)
```

Comment: He had done it differently with too many ifs but his way is more compact and intelligent. I am grateful to him. Thanks!